# node.js performance optimization and single threaded architecture

Tags: node.js

I'm running a Node.js app with express and want to start increasing its performance. Several routes are defined. Let's have an basic example:

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    User.find({}).exec(function(err, users) {
        res.json(users);
    }
});
```

Let's assume we have 3 clients A, B and C, who try to use this route. Their requests arrive on the server in the order A, B, C with 1 millisecond difference in between.

**1. If I understand the node.js architecture correctly, every request will be immediately handled, because `Users.find()` is asynchronous and there is non-blocking code?**

Let's expand this example with a synchronous call:

```
 app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
        var parameters = getUserParameters();

        User.find({parameters}).exec(function(err, users) {
            res.json(users);
        }
    });
```

Same requests, same order. `getUserParameters()` takes 50 milliseconds to complete.

**2. A will enter the route callback-function and blocks the node.js thread for 50 milliseconds. B and C won't be able to enter the function and have to wait. When A finishes `getUsersParameters()` it will continue with the asynchronous `User.find()` function and B will now enter the route callback-function. C will still have to wait for 50 more milliseconds. When B enters the asynchronous function, C's requests can be finally handled. Taken together: C has to wait 50 milliseconds for A to finish, 50 milliseconds for B to finish and 50 milliseconds for itself to finish (for simplicity, we ignore the waiting time for the asynchronous function)?**

Assuming now, that we have one more route, which is only accessible by an admin and will be called every minute through crontab.

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {  
    User.find({}).exec(function(err, users) {
        res.json(users);
    }
});

app.get('/admin-route', function (req, res) {
    blockingFunction(); // this function takes 2 seconds to complete
});
```

**3. When a request X hits `admin-route` and `blockingFunction()` is called, will A,B and C, who will call `/users` right after X's request have to wait 2 seconds until they even enter the route callback-function?**

**4. Should we make every self defined function, even if it takes only 4 milliseconds, as an asynchronous function with a callback?**

Comment: Irrelevant to this question but I have heard express is dead.

Comment: What would be a `blockingFunction` in Node/JS? Afaik, everything is modelled around the event loop.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "Yes", on #3: blocking means blocking the event loop, meaning that any I/O (like handling an HTTP request) will be blocked. In this case, the app will seem unresponsive for those 2 seconds.

However, you have to do pretty wild things for synchronous code to take 2 seconds (either very heavy calculations, or using a lot of the `*Sync()` methods provided by modules like `fs`). If you really can't make that code asynchronous, you should consider running it in a separate process.

Regarding #4: if you can easily make it asynchronous, you probably should. However, just having your synchronous function accept a callback doesn't miraculously make it asynchronous. It depends on what the function does if, and how, you can make it async.

Answer (score 0):

The ground principle is anything locking up the CPU (long-running for loops for instance) or anything using I/O or the network must be asynchronous. You could also consider moving out CPU-intensive logic out of node JS, perhaps into a Java/Python module which exposes a WebService which node JS can call.

As an aside, take a look at this module (might not be production-ready). It introduces the concept of multithreading in NodeJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads

Answer (score 0):

#3 Yes

#4 Node.js is for async programming and hence its good to follow this approach to avoid surprises in performance

Meanwhile, you can use `cluster` module of Node.js to improve performance and throughput of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to scale your application vertically first. Check out Node.js cluster module. You may utilize all the cores of the machine by spawning up workers on each core. A cluster is a pool of similar workers running under a parent Node process. Workers are spawned using the fork() method of the child_processes module. This means workers can share server handles and use inter-process communication to communicate with the parent Node process.

```js
var cluster = require('cluster')
var http = require('http')
var os = require('os')
var numCPUs = os.cpus().length

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork()
    }
} else {
    // Define express routes and listen here
}
```